# Selenium server works with Docker on MacOS but not on Jenkins

Tags: linux, selenium, docker, jenkins

I have a Selenium server image that I use with Docker as part of our test process:

```
FROM selenium/standalone-firefox:3.4.0-chromium
```

this work locally on MacOS, but when I run this Docker container on Jenkins (linux-gnu), then Selenium doesn't seem to work.

My only guess is that only a headless browser can work on Jenkins.

Does anyone know what I can do to only run a headless browser with Selenium? I am not sure if this makes sense...but I am trying to figure out why `requests to Selenium server completely timeout on Jenkins`, and I believe because barebones Linux cannot run non-headless browsers.

Comment: > Selenium doesn't seem to work.
What does this mean? Please edit the question to add some relevant information like how you are running it, what Docker version, host OS, error messages, log output from containers, etc.

Comment: All requests to Selenium timeout - when I look at the Selenium logs it seems to just keep repeating steps forwever - "finding element x", "element found", "finding element x", "element found", over and over. But then in my test code, it says it can't find element x. So weird.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are correct, depending on your configuration of your docker container, Linux docker can only run in headless mode.  Here is what I am doing to set this up:

```
stage ("Run Regression") {  
    def runTestsCommand = "dotnet test ${solutionName}/${projectName}.csproj"
                    
   def runTests =  """
          if [ -f "/usr/bin/chromedriver" ]; then
              export CHROMEDRIVER_FILEPATH=/usr/bin/chromedriver
          fi
          export NODE_ENV=jenkins
          export NO_COLOR=1
          export IP=127.0.0.1

          ${runTestsCommand}
          """    
      executeBatOrSh(runTests)
  
}
```

And here is a sample from my Docker file, where I am adding Chromium to run the tests with:

```
# Regression needs chromium
RUN echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main" > /etc/apk/repositories \
&& echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
&& echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
&& echo "http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories \
&& apk upgrade -U -a \
&& apk add \
    libstdc++ \
    chromium \
    chromium-chromedriver \
    harfbuzz \
    nss \
    freetype \
    ttf-freefont \
&& rm -rf /var/cache/* \
&& mkdir /var/cache/apk
```